# Easiest way to nest models with the same attribute into a div?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This confuses me more than anything in the world. I simply want to print html that groups/nests/combines all models with the same defined attribute into a div then get on with my life.

```
<div>
    <div>I have an attribute of red so I am here</div>
    <div>I too have an attribute of red so I am here</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Well I have an attribute of blue so I am here</div>
    <div>I have an attribute of blue so I am here as well</div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why simply wrapping the same attribute models in a div is so freaking confusing.

Its so so simple to print the same html like this, without it being wrapped, but trying to wrap it becomes a world of confusion and a lot of code.

```
<div>I have an attribute of red so I am here</div>
<div>I too have an attribute of red so I am here</div>
<div>Well I have an attribute of blue so I am here</div>
<div>I have an attribute of blue so I am here as well</div>
```

I am using backbone.js obviously, and outputting a list is so simple, but when you want to add a little more to it, it becomes a huge headache.

```
var Players = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'data/players.json',
    comparator : 'team'
});

var Player = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.app',
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        var players = new Players();
        players.fetch({
            success: function(players) {
                console.log(players);
                var template = _.template($('#appTemplate').html(), {players: players.models});
                self.$el.html(template);
            }
        });
    }
});

var EditPlayer = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.app',
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html('Works, coffee? Football?');
    }
});

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '':'home',
        'new_player': 'editPlayer'
    }
 });

var player = new Player();
var editPlayer = new EditPlayer();
var router = new Router();

router.on('route:home', function() {
    player.render();
});
router.on('route:editPlayer', function() {
    editPlayer.render();
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

Okay let me use this in a template

```
<script id="appTemplate" type="text/template">
<a href="#/new_player" class="btn btn-primary">Add Player</a>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Team</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <% _.each(players, function(player) { %>    
      <tr class="<%= player.get('team') %>">
        <td><%= player.get('firstname') %></td>
        <td><%= player.get('lastname') %></td>
        <td><%= player.get('team') %></td>
      </tr>
    <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</table> 
</script>
```

Alright I get a nice list, using the `comparator` it organizes by team, but then how do I nest each team? Do I really need to write confusing `constructor` methods, `parse` methods, or can I just rewrite my json array and go from there?

I am really lost and just hope someone can clearly explain. I don't know why you guys post in the first place, you usually make an amazing effort, I am not sure if its for the points, just to be a helping hand or what, but I am striving to be a better programmer and really need to get past this hurdle.

I just want to add I learned backbone.js from basic tutorials, so that is why I stink at these advanced topics, and its apparent I need to pickup some more advanced books/tutorials/courses, but for now i just want to figure this out!

Comment: Are you trying to group specific attributes or all attributes? For a specific attribute the easiest way to do this is probably to group your models first using something like underscores [groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) and than iterate through that in your template.

Comment: Specific attributes like team or color... Okay so it's as simple as that, Ill read as much as I can about it thanks.. An example and I can give you points :)

Comment: I'm guessing you mean one at a time, you should be able to do as I suggested. If you want I can provide a more complete example.

Comment: Thatd be awesome I can award you points :)

Comment: As a side point if your are going to be using multiple *player* views, it might be a good idea to move the compilation of your template out of the callback and into the views definition, this way it is only compiled once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what your looking to do is first group your data which you can do using something like underscore's [groupby](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) function and then iterate the groups. 
While you can do it all in the template, it will probably easier and neater to first prepare your data and send that to your template.

For example

```
 success: function(players) {
       var groupedPlayers = _.groupBy(players.models, function (player) {
             return player.get('team');
       });
       var template = _.template($('#appTemplate').html()
                       , {groupedPlayers: groupedPlayers});
        self.$el.html(template);
     }
```

Using the following template

```
<% _.each(groupedPlayers, function(team, i) {   %>   
       <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Team</>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
      <% _.each(team, function(player) { %>    
      <tr class="<%= player.get('team') %>">
        <td><%= player.get('firstname') %></td>
        <td><%= player.get('lastname') %></td>
        <td><%= player.get('team') %></td>
      </tr>
    <% }); %>
       </tbody>
    </table> 
<% }); %>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ec6Jg/3/)

Comment: Ok thanks, I appreciate it. Is there a specific json format for this to work, or just a basic ol `[{"team": "bears", player: "Jay"}, {"team": "browns", player: "Dan"}]` I would assume so because your success function works with how I have setup mine in the OP. Just want be clear and confusion free.

Comment: The example you provided should work. I'm assuming you are already using something like so perhaps just give it a try. If you get stuck I can try creating a fiddle.

Comment: You've done enough lol I really appreciate it and your time. Ill create a fiddle and you can clean it up should only take a second.

Comment: `player.get('team')` returns undefined, most likely something I am doing wrong. Here is a fiddle, I am not sure why it's not fetching from my server. http://jsfiddle.net/Ec6Jg/

Comment: I see what you're doing, the fiddle doesn't matter, but I am not quite sure why `player` is 'undefined'. I feel like once I understand that then this is as good as solved.

Comment: I don't have a brain I know this, but I have no clue why it's doing that?

Comment: Actually it's partially my fault, when you call the group by function you need to do it on the models, not the collection. Also if it is a simple group you can just specify the attribute, I'll update my answer momentarily.

Comment: AH HA I figured it out. I actually used my brain and wrote it like this `players.groupBy(function(player) {
            console.log(player);
           });` I have access to the array with this syntax.

Comment: I hope I wasn't misleading in anything I said because I probably was, but for some reason I am still getting the same result. Instead of multiple "browns" classes, I was trying to get all browns players into one "browns" div or in this case tr, but there are multiple '.browns' ? I am so sorry for being confusing. Ill mark your answer for the effort, and it should help other people, you're a good person for helping but unfortunately I have to keep seeking the answer. I am starting to HATE backbone.js!!

Comment: You just need to add what ever markup you want in between the two `each` functions in the template. I'd update it, but I'm not sure I understand how you want to have the whole team in one tr, did you perhaps mean each team in it's own table?

Comment: Well a tr is a "HORRIBLE" example hence my terrible miss communication I knew I was presenting, the example should have represented a div with perhaps a list of divs or a list of list items. My mistake there, but ultimate goal is `<div class="browns"><div class="browns-player1">browns player1</div> <div class="browns-player2">browns player2</div>`

Comment: OK have a look at my updated answer and fiddle. I changed the group by back to using a function since it didn't seem to be grouping it properly, maybe I misread the documentation on just passing an attribute.

Comment: Ok this separates it nicely, thanks so much.. Last thing is instead of adding `.browns` class twice how do I set the table to be class `.browns` so its just there once? I am not sure how to use attributes outside of the `function(player)` I dont think I can, thats the only way to access the model right? something like this instead the table class gets this team name. http://jsfiddle.net/Ec6Jg/5/

Comment: `<% _.each(groupedPlayers, function(team, i) {   %>   
       <table class="table table-bordered <%= this.team %>">`, `<% _.each(groupedPlayers, function(team, i) {   %>   
       <table class="table table-bordered <%= team.get('name') %>">` I am so sorry but I dont know if I can return attributes from the `team` argument?

Comment: Overall I really APPRECIATE everything your time, patience and kindness, this works, and is far less complicated than anything else, I am going to study the life out of this, so I never have this problem again. But if you have any ounce of whatever it is that made you help me in the first place can you explain how I add a class onto the table, or access the teams argument to get that team name?

Comment: I see teams returns a backbone.model I should be able to access it from here I hope... I didnt know you can console.log in templates!

Comment: Oh looks like `i` returns the team name, cool! I do try and read docs, but they always seem confusing, but I bet if I look at it now Ill understand why passing the `i` works... Your'e an awesome person, thanks soo much for bearing with me. Enjoy your day!

Comment: Your welcome, I'm assuming you figured out the rest (or at least that's what it sounds like).

Comment: Yup, once analyzing the code I realized I was right there was an easy solution to this, I have asked this before and got complicated answers, your's was clean, easy and effective. I just hope I dont run into any road blocks down the road but thats for me to worry about another time. Thanks Jack!